# Feeding variables into PowerShell commands in New-ADUser cmd

Tags: powershell, active-directory, powershell-cmdlet

I'm trying to feed some variables into the Powershell cmdlet New-ADuser to automate user creation. This works fine if I hard code the values but when I try to pass it variables I get the following errors:

```
New-ADUser : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'System.Object[]'.
At C:\users\test\Documents\test.ps1:103 char:1
+ New-ADUser -SamAccountName $Target -Name $TargetFullname  -UserPrincipalName [st ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [New-ADUser], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.NewADUser
```

The command is:

```
New-ADUser -SamAccountName $Target -Name $TargetFullname  -UserPrincipalName [string]::Concat($Target,"@test.local") 
-AccountPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText $TargetPassword  -Force) -Enabled $true -PasswordNeverExpires $true -Path 'CN=Users,DC=test,DC=local'
```

I get similar problems trying this with the office365 cmdlets. Am I missing a basic syntax error here?

**Edit**

Creating new question for office365 issue: 
[Argument errors with office 365 cmdlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24370610/argument-errors-with-office-365-cmdlet)

Comment: It would be better if you created a new question and check @Tim-Ferrill 's answer as answered.

Comment: Thanks, I've created a new question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it has to do with how you're building your UPN. Try wrapping that section in parentheses:

```
-UserPrincipalName ([string]::Concat($Target,"@test.local"))
```

Comment: Simply typing `"$Target@test.local"` will work as well

Comment: True. I was trying to show that it was a problem with the order of operations, but that will work as well. I've also had problems using simple concatenation like that on older versions of PowerShell.

Comment: That fixed the issue with the AD commands. See OP for updated issue! Thank you