# Argument errors with office 365 cmdlet

Tags: powershell, office365

I'm having issues feeding variables into the New-MsolUser cmdlet. I'm getting the following error.

```
New-MsolUser : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'â?UserPrincipalName ausertest@test.ie â?UsageLocation'.
At C:\users\test\Documents\test.ps1:148 char:1
+ New-MsolUser -DisplayName $TargetFullname â?"UserPrincipalName $TargetEmail  â?" ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [New-MsolUser], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.Online.Administration.Automation.NewUser
```

The code I am using is:

```
$Source = "AnotherADUser"

$TargetFname = "New"
$TargetLname = "User"

$Target = "ausertest"
$TargetFullname = [string]::Concat($TargetFname ," ", $TargetLname)

 $SourceEmail = (Get-ADUser $source -Property EmailAddress).EmailAddress
 $SourceDomain = $SourceEmail.split("@")[1]
 $TargetEmail = ([string]::Concat($Target , "@" , $SourceDomain))

New-MsolUser -DisplayName $TargetFullname –UserPrincipalName $TargetEmail  –UsageLocation "IE" | Set-MsolUserLicense -AddLicenses "TESTINSTALL:EXCHANGESTANDARD"
```

This command works when I hardcode the details..

Comment: It looks like it's choking on the value in `$TargetFullname`. Are you using the values given ("New User") or something else?

Comment: The code above are the values I'm testing against and getting the above error.

Comment: Do you still get the error if you wrap `[string]::Concat($TargetFname ," ", $TargetLname)` in parentheses?

Comment: What is the `$Target` variable in `$TargetEmail = ...`? It is not described before.

Comment: `–UserPrincipalName` and `–UsageLocation` use not the *minus* character but the character with code 8211. Maybe it's fine but try to use the standard minus instead, just to be sure.

Comment: Yes this was the issue thanks very much. Good catch. Edit: how do I set this as the accepted answer?

Comment: @RomanKuzmin Convert your comment as the `right` answer!

Comment: Done. I am glad that the guess was right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`–UserPrincipalName` and `–UsageLocation` use not the *minus* character but the
character with code 8211. Maybe it's fine but try to use the standard minus
instead, just to be sure.